# ARKit – Drawing lines/pipes/tubes relative to "CLCoordinates" and user position

Tags: swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit, scnscene

I've stucked with the task of drawing lines between coordinates. In fact I need to draw 20 tubes between some CLCoordinates. So I took as base [this project](https://github.com/ProjectDent/ARKit-CoreLocation).

I've managed to draw some tubes, but stack with the quantity. My code only can store 2 pipes, no more and I can't figure how to fix it. Also there is a huge problem with determing geoposition. The pipes are "dancing" on the screen and are not stable at coordinates.

Here is the [GitHub project](https://github.com/kosyakus/ARKit-drawPipe).

The main code is in `SceneLocationView.swift` in the Source file.

In `ViewController.swift` there are coordinates to change

Comment: So if i understand you correctly, you want to create a dotted line wherever you go in front of you? and 20 "tubes" is the range of this, as you have stated in code they are 1 cubic meter

Comment: @Vollan Actually I don't even need a dotted line. The task will be like this: I receive tube coordinates (actually I receive just an array of coordinates and then connect them by tubes) and if the person is nearby them, he can see it (if they are not far from his position). 
It is the same as if I wanted to place for example museums on the arkit. if the person is near the museum, he could see it.
And my mistake (as I think) is that I don't save the tubes in a proper way